# Is it possible to generate jasperreports subreports distributed?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, distributed

By default jasperreports uses thread to generate the subreports. But is it also possible to generate the subreports in a distributed way?

Because the number of thread is depended on your cpu, it does not scale, if you can generate the subreports on different servers, it is scalable.

Thanks